# RegEx that removes XHTML line breaks appearing before block-level tags

Tags: objective-c, regex, html-parsing, lookbehind

I need a RegEx that finds extraneous `<br />` tags that occur before block tags, leaving all other `<br />` tags intact.

Here's the text I am searching:

```
<div>some text<br id="first"/>some more text<br id="second"/></div>
```

However, when using the following RegEx:

```
</? *br.*?>(?=</? *([^(br)]).*?)
```

It selects everything past the first `<br />` tag like so:

```
<br id="first"/>some more text<br id="second"/>
```

... Which isn't what I want. How can I modify the expression so it ***only*** selects `<br id="second"/>`?

**Notes**: All inline tags ***except*** `<br />` tags are stripped out before this point, so they won't be a factor. Also, I am using Obj-C/Cocoa so I can't use all those fancy PHP functions. :). Also, this will be a valid XHTML doc.

Comment: **Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML**. You cannot reliably parse HTML with regular expressions. As soon as the HTML changes from your expectations, your code will be broken. Use a proper HTML parsing module.

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified: this will be a valid XHTML doc. Will edit my question to reflect this.

Comment: The issue isn't the validity of the HTML, but that you are basing your code on the textual representation of the document which could change and yet still be valid XHTML.

Comment: I've reread your question several times, and I still don't understand. Do you want to match the second `<br/>` tag because a `</div>` tag follows immediately? What *exactly* is your rule for matching?

Comment: @AndyLester: Fair enough, but my question isn't that I am starting a project, and what approach should I take. I have existing, working code that uses RegEx along with NSXMLParser (a parsing module) that does the job within acceptable limits. An answer to my question will inch the success rate up a little more.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: The rule is: match any `<br/>` tag that appears immediately before another tag, as long as it *isn't* another `<br/>` tag. Is that clear? Explaining my intentions of RegEx in plain English isn't my strong suit :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<br[^<>]*>(?=\s*<(?!br))
```

should do what you want. [(See it here)](http://regex101.com/r/hI7aY1)

**Explanation of the regex:**

```
<br     # Match <br
[^<>]*  # followed by any number of non-bracket characters
>       # and a >.
(?=     # Assert that we are right before...
 \s*    # optional whitespace,
 <      # followed by any tag
 (?!br) # except br
)       # (End of lookahead)
```

**Some comments:**

- I've removed the optional slashes from your regex because `</br>` doesn't exist in HTML or XHTML.
- I've also removed the optional spaces at the start of the tags because there may be no whitespace between `<` and the tag name (nor may there be whitespace between `/` and `>`).
- As an aside: In valid XHTML, `<br />` is the only legal form; `<br id="foo" />` is invalid.